# How to quickly try out Java code?

Tags: java

When I'm coding in Python and I want to try something out, I open IDLE of Python on the command line and am able to quickly try something out. Is there a similar way I could do that for Java?

I have heard about Java "shells" (e.g. http://www.beanshell.org/). Has anyone tried them?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? If yes then definitely check this application http://krillapps.com/coderunner/

Comment: drJava has a nice interactions pane to try

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787313/is-there-any-python-like-interactive-console-for-java). Wouldn't a Smalltalk-like workspace be nice in Java though? ;-)

Comment: Hi rdasxy, questions about development tools, including recommendations for specific tasks, are off-topic here: for that, you want our sister site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). However, check out the link aaamos gave before attempting to reask there.

Comment: http://jpad.io allows running java code snippets and viewing the results in a nice GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) is perhaps better suited to your needs. As wikipedia notes, "Most Java code is also syntactically valid Groovy."

Here's an [example](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) of a Groovy web console

Comment: I'd argue that this environment is impure.

Answer (score 4):

If you download the free [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) IDE you can use the code pad area to try out snippets of code on the fly.

[image: BlueJ Code Pad]

Answer (score 3):

If you have Eclipse open and a program in debug I like to use the Display window to quickly test out Java code snippets real time.  If I am not debugging something I generally just code snippets into a JUnit test case and run them to see what happens.

I know it is not the best way but it is often good enough for my needs.

Comment: +1 It might miss some notoriety, but the Display window is very useful to prototype dynamically some code. I use it often at debug time. It is very similar to the Immediate window for the people familiar to the VB / VBA IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [ideone](http://ideone.com/). Offers many languages, including Java.

> ideone is something more than a pastebin; it's an online compiler and debugging tool which allows to compile and run code online in more than 40 programming languages...
>
> Choose a programming language, enter your source code and input data into text boxes. Then check or uncheck *run code* (whether to execute your program) and *private* (whether not to list your code in the [recent codes](http://ideone.com/recent) page) checkboxes, click the submit button and watch your snippet being executed...

Comment: It isn't really a time saver IMHO.

Comment: @Chiron: Why are you saying that? For me, it is: you just type in your code and can execute it immediately. What else could you expect?